# Understanding JQuery Docs on $.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Where in the JQuery Docs are these parameters?

```
jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

For example, I tried searching what `data` would be and cannot find it.

Also, I see examples like `.done( function( msg ){} )` or

```
// Create a deferred object
var dfd = $.Deferred();
// Add handlers to be called when dfd is resolved
dfd
// .done() can take any number of functions or arrays of functions
.done( [ fn1, fn2 ], fn3, [ fn2, fn1 ] )
// We can chain done methods, too
.done(function( n ) {
$( "p" ).append( n + " we're done." );
});
```

So I am clearly confused about how the parameters are passed to this function.

I need to get the `responseText` I think, I am echoing a number in PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [jQuery .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The **data** returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status;
>   and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

You want the `data`; that's your server response.

Comment: What's up with the example I put where .done( function( n ){} ), receives a `n` parameter? What will it be `data`?

Comment: JS parameters are not required, so whatever you call the first one is the first parameter. In that case `n` is your `data`.

Comment: So, I will have these parameters available `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});` and then I will be able to use them, in order, with any name ?

Answer (score 1):

.done is the same as the success callback in your JQuery.ajax properties. The callback is described here: as follows:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

success
**Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )**

.done takes 1-n functions or arrays of functions which should get invoked on success of your ajax call

`data` is simply the data you receive as response from the server, some json object...

Answer (score 0):

When you register a callback with a promise's `.done()` method, this callback will be passed the parameter that this promise will be resolved with: `promise.resolve(data)`. In the case of a jQuery Ajax request, the servers response body is the data that the XHR promise is resolved with.